# rhr package :brownian bridge analysis error

Tags: r

I have run into a problem within the rhr package using the GUI.
I upload my dataset and give my data the input EPSG of 4326 and output EPSG of 32750.

Calculating the KDE works fine, but the Brownian bridge does not seem to work and i get this error:

```
Timing stopped at: 27.78 0.15 28.08
Warning: Error in return: multi-argument returns are not permitted
Stack trace (innermost first):
     72: FUN
     71: lapply
     70: rhrHrAnalysis
     69: system.time
     68: eval [C:\Users\Sam\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\rhr\gui/server.R#774]
     67: eval
     66: withProgress
     59: isolate
     58: observerFunc [C:\Users\Sam\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\rhr\gui/server.R#673]
 2: shiny::runApp
 1: rhrGUI
```

Any idea on how to solve this?
Much appreciated,
Sam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the Wyoming Migration Mapper for brownian bridge?  It allows you to do dynamic or regular brownian bridge analysis and lets you select the migration dates visually in a GUI.  It is done through R and is probably the best for this type of analysis.  I've been having problems with rhr recently also.  http://migrationinitiative.org/content/migration-mapper